# Vue Loading Overlay Component not working in nuxt2 .0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, loader

I'm using [vue-loading-overlay](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay)

1. `plugins/vueloadingoverlaylibrary.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
// import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';
Vue.use(Loading)
```

2. `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [ 
  '@/plugins/vueloadingoverlaylibrary.js'
]
```

3. Getting error

> TypeError
> (0 , external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_amd_vue_root_Vue_.createStaticVNode) is not a function

I am using nuxt v.2x but working fine in vue2.x version. But not working for nuxt2.x.

Comment: Are you using the v3 of the package? https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay/tree/v3.x#installation

Comment: ` "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.2.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",`  @kissu

Comment: working fine down grade: "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.4.2",

Comment: Does it work fine with `3.4.2`? Solves your issue?

Comment: Yes working fine

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

OP achieved a working `vue-loading-overlay` by using the `v3.4.2` version.